# Vue.js using a $route.name to hide part of component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to hide part of component when `$route.name` takes some values:

```
<div v-if="$route.name === 'somename'">
  ...
</div>
```

The problem is that `$route.name` doesn't load immediately. Part of component may hide not immediately. It looks like a blinking.
Is there way to check that `$route.name` is loaded? 
Or maybe there is another way to solve this issue?

Comment: Show a short example illustrating your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shorthand syntax, doing

`<div v-if="$route.name && $route.name === 'somename'">
  ...
</div>`

It means you will render your component just if there is some $route.name and it equals to 'somename'